# Pandas: Skip an arbitrary number of lines in read_csv() before making data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file that looks like this:

```
##bunch of lines
##lines, lines and more lines
##lines
#Chr  field1  field2  field3
```

I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
```

And I get the error

```
Error tokenising data: Expected 1 field in line 2, saw 2
```

I understand the error, that it sees a comma in the second line, but not the first. No matter what delimiter I use, I will always get an error like that because some of the header lines (the ones with ##) have tabs, commas etc.

I actually want to remove all the lines that start with ## anyway (it's a .vcf file), and I want to just start my parsing at the line with #Chr (i.e. I want the rest of the file to be a data frame, where the line #Chr field1 field2 field3 is the header and everything below it is the data frame).

I know you can skip lines in pandas with `skiprows`, but my problem is that each file I read in will be skipping a different number of ## lines.

Would anyone know of a way to read in csv with pandas, where I can say 'skip all the lines beginning with ##, and then start a dataframe from the line with #Chr and make that line the header?

Answer (score 0):

`pd.read_csv()` provides with a `on_bad_lines` argument which should fix your problem

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Thanks, yea when I add in on_bad_lines (actually ```error_bad_lines = False``` because it's an old version of pandas and I'm not allowed to change it), the shape of the output file is (6,1), whereas when I read in the exact same file without ```error_bad_lines = False``` I get the above error, the file is exactly this file format: https://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/Variant%20Call%20Format/vcf-variant-call-format-version-40/

Comment: (and the shape should be (6869,211), after you skip all the double ## lines).

Comment: Which pandas version? You could just pre-process the file by opening it and dropping the bad lines, if that's not much. I am out of ideas otherwise.